# Need to get data from specific part of the JSON String

Tags: apex, json, field-update

I have a field which has the JSON string. I just need to populate a part of that string into different field is that possible?

log__c = JSON={"eventPayload":{"units":1.00,"name":"D-00889","applied_for":null}

I just want to display D-00889 in a new field, how can we do this.

Hope I am clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest and still kinda smart way to do it is to use [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)
(provide there you're example JSON) that way you'll have data structure into which you can deserialize given JSON using

```
JSON2Apex obj = (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
```

After that you can just get that field by simple reference.

Comment: can we do it using a workflow or formula field, Log__c is a text field

Comment: You can't parse JSON using workflow rule and using formula is not a good idea (i think it could be possible using regexp though). Still I dont see why Log__c being a text field is a problem? It would deserialize to an object with fields that would be a string so you will just need to do something like log__c = obj.eventPayload.name and you'll have your result

Answer (score -2):

It seems like this string is saved in a field.

Assuming the string is like below which is not a valid JSON string too:
{"eventPayload":{"units":1.00,"name":"D-00889","applied_for":null}

Even though using a wrapper class is recommended, if you have really wanted to use a formula, assuming your string never changes that much and you name is always 7 characters you can use this formula:

```
MID(Log__c, FIND("name", Log__c)+ 7 , 7)
```

This will give you: `D-00889`